# Create Folder, Create AD Groups, Apply Groups to Folder and Set Permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, share, ntfs

I'm trying to find a much cleaner way of creating a network share folder, creating an Active Directory Security group that matches the share, and then applying the levels of permissions to the folder all while asking the questions in the script.

- Create folder `D:\Test Share`
- Share as Test Share
- Create AD Group `FS-TESTSHARE-R`
- Create AD Group `FS-TESTSHARE-RW`
- Apply Both groups to the new share folder
- Set Full Read permissions to `FS-TESTSHARE-R`
- Set Full Read/Rights permissions to `FS-TESTSHARE-RW`
- Set full access permissions to `Domain Admins`

This is what I have so far and am completely lost as to how to get the rest and make it work:

```
$Path = 'c:\TestShare'

# create new folder
$null = New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory

# get permissions
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path

# add a new permission
$permission = 'domain\FS-TESTSHARE-RW', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# set new permissions
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
```

Comment: you'r question so Confusing you have all command just use read-host command get value of your variable like $null = read-host "enter name of share folder"

Comment: Please focus on one thing at a time when asking questions on SO. As it stands an answer to your question would boil down to writing the script for you, as it isn't particularly clear which specific problem you're asking about.

Comment: My question is a single question... I'm trying to figure out how to do everything I asked in 1 large script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while asking the questions in the script

In order to get the input, it's best to use the param construct at the top of your .ps1 file like so

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string] $Path,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string[]] $permission)
```

You can then provide the values when launching the script like so

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -path 'c:\TestShare' -permission ('domain\FS-TESTSHARE-RW', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
```

This gives you a couple of advantages over read-host. For starters you can enforce the type and that the value provided is not null or empty, but also it allows all values to be collected up front, meaning the script can be used in automated scenarios, unlike Read-Host which only works with a human inputting the values.

> Creating an Active Directory Security group that matches the Share

You can use the [Active Directory PowerShell Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) to create and update groups.

Create the group using the [New-ADGroup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617258.aspx) command

```
New-ADGroup -Name "FS-TESTSHARE-RW" -SamAccountName "FS-TESTSHARE-RW" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Test Share Read-Write" -Path "CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com" -Description "Members of this group have read-write access to the test share"
```

Then use the [Add-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) command to add principals to the group. The following example would add the principals User1 and User2 to the group FS-TESTSHARE-RW.

```
Add-ADGroupMember FS-TESTSHARE-RW User1,User2
```

As for mapping the permissions, you are already on the correct path, however I will point out that you shouldn't use $null in your scripts for values, as [it is an automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847768.aspx)

> $null is an automatic variable that contains a NULL or empty value. You
>          can use this variable to represent an absent or undefined value in commands
>          and scripts.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Quick question on using a variable in the script though. How do I use the variable to create the group and the folder, or do I need a new variable? 

Example: $Path = 'c:\TestShare' creates the share on the c drive, but I want the AD group to use TestShare. So does that mean I need to create a new variable such as $ADGroup = 'TESTSHARE' or is it possible to use the same $Path variable and remove the "c:" portion somehow and make it come across in all capital letters?

Comment: And to insert that into the group name would it be 
|

`New-ADGroup -Name "FS-$ADGROUP-RW" -SamAccountName "FS-$ADGROUP-RW" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "$ADGROUP Read-Write" -Path "CN=Security Groups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com" -Description "Members of this group have read-write access to $path"`

Comment: In that case you are probably better using 2 variables, 1 for the parent container, and another for the Name.
`$parent = "C:\"; $Name = "TESTSHARE";
`
Then use them together for the full path

`$path = "$($parent)$($Name)"`

Comment: Apparently I don't have the ability to add my new script here in the comments since it is too long... I created a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488395/single-powershell-script-to-create-folder-ad-groups-and-apply-new-groups-to-fo